# Reading crash report about Navigation Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, crash, uikit

I hate to simply post a crash report for my iOS app here, but I am in some dire need of help to understand it. It looks to me like something is crashing in a view or navigation animation, but I can't tell where. Has anyone seen any crash reports like this? Is it outside the scope of my code?
The last reference to my `MyApp` is in `main.m`, which doesn't make much sense to me.

Any advice on how to interpret this would be majorly helpful, and greatly appreciated. I'm just now learning to read these things correctly, and the more help I get, the more I learn.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x341975be _objc_msgSend + 30
1   UIKit                               0x333fbd7d -[UIImageView isAnimating] + 137
2   UIKit                               0x333ffb43 -[UIImageView stopAnimating] + 103
3   UIKit                               0x333ffa89 -[UIActivityIndicatorView _tearDownAnimation] + 37
4   UIKit                               0x333ffa1d -[UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] + 25
5   UIKit                               0x333ff983 -[UIActivityIndicatorView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 55
6   UIKit                               0x333ff5bf -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1119
7   UIKit                               0x333ff5bf -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1119
8   UIKit                               0x333ff5bf -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1119
9   UIKit                               0x333ff5bf -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1119
10  UIKit                               0x333f9e4b -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 139
11  UIKit                               0x335c541b __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 219
12  UIKit                               0x3340d8a7 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 159
13  UIKit                               0x3345df01 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 93
14  UIKit                               0x333f4ab3 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 159
15  UIKit                               0x334698cf -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 51
16  QuartzCore                          0x36cc8bd9 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 209
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3859f4b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x385a41bd _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 225
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3a280f3b __CFRunLoopRun + 1291
20  CoreFoundation                      0x3a1f3ebd _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
21  CoreFoundation                      0x3a1f3d49 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
22  GraphicsServices                    0x385c12eb _GSEventRunModal + 75
23  UIKit                               0x334332f9 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
24  MyApp                               0x0003706d main (main.m:45)
```

Comment: may be this helps- http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: What view were you navigating away from when this crash occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Comment out a major part of your code to see if the error occurs from there. If it does, then narrow the commenting down. Start with a method containing animation as the log suggests. I don't know if there is a better way, but this is the way I do it if I don't have further information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application running just fine until "[UIImageView isAnimation]" and then crashed. You may check out nearby this line. But I suggest that you could enable zombie object to see where is going wrong.

Comment: The caller of that method isn't in the questioner's code. In fact, none of the frames in that thread are in the questioner's code. So, without having the UIKit source code, there is no “this line” to “check out nearby”. Using Instruments's Zombies template is a good idea, though.

Comment: Oh,sure,my fault.I didn't notice the 'UIKit', but I'm glad to contribute a good idea,may it help.